# delay page reload until jquery script finishes it job

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am making simple webpage for my wife.

I am using this script as menu : http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/examples/

Because I dont want to reload whole page after clicking on menu, I am using `pjax` method (`ajax` + `pushState`)

The link to the page where the problem occurs: http://sk-architekci.pl/sknowy2/ 
(please open it in IE and click "PROJEKTY" in menu on the left, then do the same in Firefox for example)

**My problem:**

Everything is working great in browsers which support `pushState` method ( yes IE doesn't support it). In every browser except IE when I click on some link in menu, the menu slowly expands and the content is loaded to the proper div.

In IE when I click on some link in my menu, the script is not able to finish its work because whole page reloads. Menu is jumping instead of slowly reload.

**My question:**

Is there a way to delay page reload until menu script finishes its job ? or maybe there is some other "dirty" and not elegant, but effective solution for my problem.

**my JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion-1').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: true,
        disableLink: false,
        speed: 'fast',
        showCount: false,
        autoExpand: false,
        cookie: 'dcjq-accordion-1'
    });
});
```

I am not web developer or programmer, I dont know jquery well, that is why please give me simple answer if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with dcAccordian. However, there is a setting for `disableLink`. What happens if you set it to "true"? `disableLink  : true,    // Disable all links of parent items`

Comment: disableLink : true - it means that script will disable all links in my menu and the wont be clicable any more. It is rather bad for me, because those links must be active in order to load content into my page. This ofcourse fix my IE problem but makes my meny useless for me hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but what you can try is

Add this at the beginning of your head tag:

```
$(function(){
  $('body').hide();
});
```

And at the very end, add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').show();
});
```

This would hide everything until all scripting has been done. I use this as a workaround for flash of unstyled content.

Comment: hmmm... where should I put this code?? maybe this will help, but I dont know where it should be placed?

Comment: At the end of the body tag.

Comment: `$(function(){});`  and   `$(document).ready(function(){});` are same..see my edit

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari It's not the functions themselves that are the solution. It's the sequence in which they are written. The first one will execute first. So, if the the one to show the contents are written at the end then the contents would be hidden until everything is rendered.

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari The problem with doing that is that the callback function would be executed immediately after the hide() function completes. The aim is to delay show until the end. I hope you understand what I am trying to do here. Besides, like I said I am not sure if this would help the OP with his exact problem. Would be nice if he'd left a comment or something :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect my intentions more clearly :) This does work for me with the fouc problem. I guess this is something similar.

Comment: ya..its fine..but wouldn't it differ for browsers like IE...I think timeout is a good idea...

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari How would you know how much time it takes to render the DOM?